# Change label value on changing textbox value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

How to change my label value when my textbox value changes. here is my code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GoogleMap.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head><title>Google Map</title>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&   sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         var map, directionsService, directionsDisplay, geocoder, startLatlng, endLatlng, routeStart, routeEnd, startMarker, endMarker, dragTimer, placeService, airportMarkers = [];

    function initialize() {
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
         routeStart = document.getElementById('routeStart');
         autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(routeStart);
         routeEnd = document.getElementById('routeEnd');
         autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(routeEnd);
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
         directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
             suppressMarkers: true
         });
        var myOptions = {
             zoom: 12,
             center: latlng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             mapTypeControl: false
         };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
          placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

          var form = document.getElementById("routeForm");
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var start = this.elements["routeStart"].value;
             var end = this.elements["routeEnd"].value;
 
             if (start.length && end.length) {
                 calcRoute(start, end);
             }
         });

          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',     function() {
            var directions = this.getDirections();
            var overview_path = directions.routes[0].overview_path;
            var startingPoint = overview_path[0];
            var destination = overview_path[overview_path.length - 1];
            addMarker(startingPoint, 'start');
            addMarker(destination, 'end');
         });
     }

    function addMarker(position, type) 
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map
         });

         marker.type = type;

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
            var marker = this;
            clearTimeout(dragTimer);
             // only update the location if 250ms has passed since last drag
             dragTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                 getLocationName(marker.getPosition(), function(name) {
                    if (marker.type === 'start') {
                         routeStart.value = name;
                     } else {
                        routeEnd.value = name;
                    }
                });
           }, 250);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            calcRoute(startMarker.getPosition(), endMarker.getPosition());
        });

         if (type === 'start') {
            startMarker = marker;
         } else {
             endMarker = marker;
        }
    }

     function displayAirports() {
         placeService.textSearch({
         location: startMarker.getPosition(),
         query: 'airport near, ' + routeEnd.value,
         radius: '100',
         types: ['airport']
          }, function(airports, status) {
             if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                 for (var a in airports) {
                     airportMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: airports[a].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    }

      function getLocationName(latlng, callback) {
        geocoder.geocode({
             location: latlng
         }, function(result, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var i = -1,
                    locationName = 'Not Found';
  
                 // find the array index of the last object with the locality type
                 for (var c = 0; c < result.length; c++) {
                     for (var t = 0; t < result[c].types.length; t++) {
                        if (result[c].types[t].search('locality') > -1) {
                           i = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (i > -1) {
                     locationName = result[i].address_components[0].long_name;
                }
                 callback(locationName);
            }
        });
    }

     function calcRoute(start, end) {
        var request = {
             origin: start,
             destination: end,
             travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
         };
         directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                displayAirports();
            }
         });
     }
     function GetVal(textBoxValue) {
          document.getElementById('<%=Value1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = textBoxValue;

     }
     function GetVal2(textBoxValue) {
          document.getElementById('<%=Value2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = textBoxValue;
     }
    </script>
     </head>
       <body onload="initialize()">
            <form id="routeForm" runat="server">
            Start &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="routeStart" runat="server"   onchange="GetVal(this.value)" />&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="routeStart" 
                ErrorMessage="Enter origin city" ForeColor="Red">* Enter origin   city</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             &nbsp;
     End<asp:TextBox ID="routeEnd" runat="server" onchange="GetVal2(this.value);"  />&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
            runat="server" ControlToValidate="routeEnd" 
                 ErrorMessage="Enter destination city" ForeColor="Red">* Enter destination city</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Find Route" />
           <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Value1" runat="server"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Value2" runat="server"/>
            </form>
            <div class="clear">
                 <div id="directionsPanel" style="float: right; width: 20%; height: 533px">
                 </div>
              </div>
             <div id="map_canvas" style="float: left; width: 80%; height: 700px;">
            </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Is there strict requirement to use javascript in doing this.And is value1 and Value2 the label controls.

Comment: the error is when i move my marker on google map textbox value changes but label value remain same

Comment: yes i have to do it in javascript but you can give me other alternative to @abide mesaraure and value1 and value2 are my labels

Comment: What event is populating your textbox?

Comment: I have just updated my answer

Comment: i edit my code this is my whole code now what i want i enter start and end place on my textbox and pree Find route button when i do so i found marker on both the location with distance and enter location can be seen in label now when i chage my marker or start or end it change into textbox and so in label my my label value didnt change according to textbox value

Comment: i guess u get what i am trying to say

Comment: Yes I can get what you are saying..Did you try my suggestion on text changed.

Comment: @AbideMasaraure whats is routeStart_textChanged?? and can u tell me where i have to put your code in code behind page as i m bit confused by ur answer

Comment: Thats an event handler to handle the text changed event.Are you you sing vb or c#.

Comment: iam using C#@AbideMasaraure

Comment: I have updated my answer.Paste the code  anywhere inside the class declaration in your code behind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22573/discussion-between-abide-masaraure-and-amitesh)

Answer (score 1):

It would make your life much  easier by simply hooking to the the on textchanged event of your textbox and assigning the value of your label in code behind.

**Mark Up**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="routeStart" runat="server" OnTextChanged="routeStart_textChanged"    AutoPostBack="True" />
```

**Code Behind**

**VB**

```
 Protected Sub routeStart_textChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

  Label1.Text="New Value"

  End Sub
```

**C#**

```
  protected void routeStart_textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Label1.Text = "New Value";

    }
```

If it is the only requirement to use java script then I assume somewhere in your page you have this line

```
   routeStart.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "GetVal('" + routeStart.Text + "' );");
```

You don't need the onchange atrribute in your mark up.It will make Visual studio unhappy though that also works.

Answer (score 1):

The `onchange` event fires when you navigate away from the textbox (e.g. when the textbox loses focus). Therefore, you won't see the changes while typing.

To make sure your function is called as you are typing, use `onkeyup` event instead

```
<asp:TextBox ID="routeStart" runat="server" onkeyup="GetVal(this.value)" />
```

Comment: i am using this in google map so when i use onkeyup my marker move to different place and won't stop